# Syntax Error in python Flask Triangle

Tags: angularjs, flask

Since I wanted to use AngularJS in combination with Flask, I searched for a cool tool to handle these frameworks properly since Jinja and Angular would have problems with each other. I found [Triangle](http://flask-triangle.readthedocs.org/en/develop/index.html) which is pretty cool and working but just up to a certain point. Stuff like this works for example:

```
<a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link|angular}}">
    {{post.title|angular}}
</a>
```

But on the other hand this does not work:

```
<span>
    <a href="#/posts/{{$index|angular}}">Comments</a>
</span>
```

When I try to do that, I receive following error

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError
>
> TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char u'$' at 875

Am I doing something wrong or is the framework just limited in that case? Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `$`s are not valid in Python identifiers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message is saying, `$` cannot be used in [Jinja as part of a variable](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#variables).

Instead, you'll need to [change Angular's delimiter notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30362956/2676531):

> ```
> var app = angular.module('Application', []);
>
> app.config(['$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider) {
>   $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{a');
>   $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('a}');
> }]);
> ```
>
> Whatever is chosen for the start and end symbols will act as the new delimiters. In this case, you would express a variable > to Angular using {a some_variable a}.

Answer (score 4):

Just looking at the angular filter code, and it looks like that quoting a string and applying angular filter should work fine.

```
<span>
    <a href="#/posts/{{'$index'|angular}}">Comments</a>
</span>
```

Below is the angular filter code copied from https://github.com/morgan-del/flask-triangle

```
def angular_filter(value):
    """
    A filter to tell Jinja2 that a variable is for the AngularJS template
    engine.
    If the variable is undefined, its name will be used in the AngularJS
    template, otherwise, its content will be used.
    """

    if is_undefined(value):
        return '{{{{{}}}}}'.format(value._undefined_name)
    if type(value) is bool:
        value = repr(value).lower()
    return '{{{{{}}}}}'.format(value)
```