# Using Flask_wtf inside angularJS ng-app

Tags: python, angularjs, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a form created with Flask_wtf. Now I trying to add in angularJS to do the username/password min-length validation etc on the form.

1. I tried:
   Flask-WTF to create the form and handle submit button press

   > ```
   > _form = LoginForm()  # Flask-WTF: Construct a LoginForm
   > if _form.validate_on_submit():  # POST request with valid data?
   > # Retrieve POST parameters
   > _username = _form.username.data
   > _passwd   = _form.passwd.data
   > ```
2. I tried:
   Form.html

   > ```
   > {% import 'macros.html' as macros %}
   >
   > {% extends "base.html" %}{# in app_main's templates folder #}
   > {% block title %}Login{% endblock %}
   > {% block content %}
   > {{ super() }}{# Render the contents of the parent block #}
   > <h1>Login</h1>
   >
   > <!-- loginpage -->
   > <form method="POST">
   >   {{ form.hidden_tag() }}{# Render any hidden fields, including the CSRF #}
   >
   >   <div class="field">{{ form.username.label }} {{ form.username }}</div>
   >   {{ macros.show_field_errors(form.username.errors) }}
   >
   >   <div class="field">{{ form.passwd.label }} {{ form.passwd }}</div>
   >   {{ macros.show_field_errors(form.passwd.errors) }}
   >
   >   <div class="field">{{ form.submit }}</div>
   > </form>   
   >
   > <div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="loginController">
   >  ........
   > </div><!--end of ng-app-->
   > {% endblock %}
   > ```
   >
   > **Issue:
   >   Putting my loginpage outside the ng-app < div > and submit button works well. But when I put it inside ng-app < div > the submit button will no longer work. Am I missing something?**
3. I already changed Angular $interpolateProvider

   ```
   var app = angular.module('mainApp', []).config(function($interpolateProvider) {
   $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
   $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
   ```
4. I already checked other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362950/is-it-possible-to-use-angular-with-the-jinja2-template-engine) ,it does not resolve my issue by changing interpolate.

Thanks for your time!